# While running Hibernate Criteria, HQL query is not created in given order

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

While running Hibernate Criteria, HQL query is not created in given order
and shows Exception

```
  ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:131 - Unknown column 'stsup4_.SUPPLIER_ID' in 'on clause'
```

The Generated HQL is not created in expected order.
When I run the same generated HQL in mysql with some changes, I get output.

Java Code is given Below

```
        Session session = connector.getSession();
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(ST_PRODUCTMASTER.class, "ST_PRODUCT");
        cr.createCriteria("ST_PRODUCT.ST_PRODUCT_MANUFACTURER_PARENT", "STPRODMAN", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN, Restrictions.eq("PROD_MAN_STATUS", "ACTIVE"));
        cr.createCriteria("STPRODMAN.ST_MANUFACTURER", "STMAN", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
        cr.createCriteria("ST_PRODUCT.ST_PRODUCT_SUPPLIER_PARENT", "STPRODSUP", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN, Restrictions.eq("PROD_SUPPLIER_STATUS", "ACTIVE"));
        cr.createCriteria("STPRODSUP.ST_SUPPLIER", "STSUP", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
        cr.createCriteria("ST_PRODUCT.ST_PRODUCT_RATES", "ZSTPR", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN,  Restrictions.eqProperty("ST_SUPPLIER.SUPPLIER_ID", "STSUP.SUPPLIER_ID"));
        cr.createCriteria("ST_PRODUCT.ST_MEDICINE_CATEGORY", "MEDI_CAT", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
        cr.createCriteria("ST_PRODUCT.ST_TAX_MASTER", "TAX", JoinType.INNER_JOIN);
        cr.createCriteria("ST_PRODUCT.ST_UNIT", "UNIT", JoinType.INNER_JOIN);
        cr.add(Restrictions.eq("ST_PRODUCT.PRODUCT_STATUS", "ACTIVE"));


        ProjectionList p1 = Projections.projectionList();
        p1.add(Projections.property("ST_PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID"));
        p1.add(Projections.property("ST_PRODUCT.PRODUCT_NAME"));
        p1.add(Projections.property("UNIT.UNIT_DISPLAY_UNIT"));
        p1.add(Projections.property("TAX.TAX_PURCHASE"));
        p1.add(Projections.property("ST_PRODUCT.PRODUCT2_DISCOUNT"));
        p1.add(Projections.property("ST_PRODUCT.PRODUCT2_DIS_AMOUNT"));
        p1.add(Projections.property("ST_MEDICINE_CATEGORY.CAT_CATEGORY_ID"));
        p1.add(Projections.property("MEDI_CAT.CAT_SHORT_NAME"));
        p1.add(Projections.property("UNIT.UNIT_ID"));
        p1.add(Projections.property("TAX.TAX_ID"));
        //MANUFACTURER
        p1.add(Projections.property("STMAN.MAN_ID"));
        p1.add(Projections.property("STPRODMAN.BASE_LEVEL"));
        p1.add(Projections.property("STPRODMAN.FREE_QTY"));
        //SUPPLIER
        p1.add(Projections.property("STSUP.SUPPLIER_ID"));
        p1.add(Projections.property("STPRODSUP.BASE_LEVEL"));
        p1.add(Projections.property("STPRODSUP.FREE_QTY"));

        cr.setProjection(p1);
        List l = cr.list();
        System.out.println("Size items::" + l.size());
```

ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:131 - Unknown column 'stsup4_.SUPPLIER_ID' in 'on clause'
This it the SQL generated by Hibernate

```
    select
    this_.PRODUCT_ID as y0_,
    this_.PRODUCT_NAME as y1_,
    unit8_.UNIT_DISPLAY_UNIT as y2_,
    tax7_.TAX_PURCHASE as y3_,
    this_.PRODUCT2_DISCOUNT as y4_,
    this_.PRODUCT2_DIS_AMOUNT as y5_,
    this_.CAT_CATEGORY_ID as y6_,
    medi_cat6_.CAT_SHORT_NAME as y7_,
    unit8_.UNIT_ID as y8_,
    tax7_.TAX_ID as y9_,
    stman2_.MAN_ID as y10_,
    stprodman1_.BASE_LEVEL as y11_,
    stprodman1_.FREE_QTY as y12_,
    stsup4_.SUPPLIER_ID as y13_,
    stprodsup3_.BASE_LEVEL as y14_,
    stprodsup3_.FREE_QTY as y15_ 
from
    ST_PRODUCTMASTER this_ 
left outer join
    ST_MEDICINE_CATEGORY medi_cat6_ 
        on this_.CAT_CATEGORY_ID=medi_cat6_.CAT_CATEGORY_ID 
left outer join
    ST_PRODUCT_MANUFACTURER stprodman1_ 
        on this_.PRODUCT_ID=stprodman1_.PRODUCT_ID 
        and (
            stprodman1_.PROD_MAN_STATUS=? 
        ) 
left outer join
    ST_MANUFACTURER stman2_ 
        on stprodman1_.MAN_ID=stman2_.MAN_ID 
left outer join
    ST_PRODUCT_RATES zstpr5_ 
        on this_.PRODUCT_ID=zstpr5_.PRODUCT_ID 
        and (
            zstpr5_.SUPPLIER_ID=stsup4_.SUPPLIER_ID 
        ) 
left outer join
    ST_PRODUCT_SUPPLIER stprodsup3_ 
        on this_.PRODUCT_ID=stprodsup3_.PRODUCT_ID 
        and (
            stprodsup3_.PROD_SUPPLIER_STATUS=? 
        ) 
left outer join
    ST_SUPPLIER stsup4_ 
        on stprodsup3_.SUPPLIER_ID=stsup4_.SUPPLIER_ID 
inner join
    ST_TAX_MASTER tax7_ 
        on this_.TAX_ID=tax7_.TAX_ID 
inner join
    ST_UNIT unit8_ 
        on this_.UNIT_ID=unit8_.UNIT_ID 
where
    (
        this_.PRODUCT_DELETED <> 'DELETED'
    ) 
    and this_.PRODUCT_STATUS=?
```

**zstpr5_**   is generated before  **stsup4_**   
and thus zstpr5_.SUPPLIER_ID=stsup4_.SUPPLIER_ID 
is not accessible

```
 left outer join
    ST_PRODUCT_RATES zstpr5_ 
        on this_.PRODUCT_ID=zstpr5_.PRODUCT_ID 
        and (
            zstpr5_.SUPPLIER_ID=stsup4_.SUPPLIER_ID 
        ) 
left outer join
    ST_PRODUCT_SUPPLIER stprodsup3_ 
        on this_.PRODUCT_ID=stprodsup3_.PRODUCT_ID 
        and (
            stprodsup3_.PROD_SUPPLIER_STATUS=? 
        ) 
left outer join
    ST_SUPPLIER stsup4_ 
        on stprodsup3_.SUPPLIER_ID=stsup4_.SUPPLIER_ID
```

ACTUAL EXPECTED ORDER IS

```
left outer join
    ST_PRODUCT_SUPPLIER stprodsup3_ 
        on this_.PRODUCT_ID=stprodsup3_.PRODUCT_ID 
        and (
            stprodsup3_.PROD_SUPPLIER_STATUS=? 
        ) 
left outer join
    ST_SUPPLIER stsup4_ 
        on stprodsup3_.SUPPLIER_ID=stsup4_.SUPPLIER_ID 
left outer join
    ST_PRODUCT_RATES zstpr5_ 
        on this_.PRODUCT_ID=zstpr5_.PRODUCT_ID 
        and (
            zstpr5_.SUPPLIER_ID=stsup4_.SUPPLIER_ID 
        )
```

Hibernate is generating a number with table name, 
1_, 2_ , 3_

even though while creating SQL this order is not maintained,
it is not even created in the order we give.

Comment: can you please post your mapping file? if its too big then a link to it might do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't posted your mapping file, I'll explain how Hibernate orders the joins.

Hibernate uses the mapping xml file to figure out the order of joins, so if you have a relation in it (one-to-many or any other tag) for that table, just move it above the other table's tag.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.javaquery.com/2014/10/how-hibernate-interpret-order-of-join.html).